# Why won't my jQuery function detect element visibility in viewport?

Tags: jquery

This question is related to one I posted 20 hrs ago. I still cannot resolve it, having tried 2-3 methods. What I want to do is detect visibility of an HTML element called #cover and perform an animation on that element. By "visibility" I mean partial or complete visibility in the device viewport.

.is(:visible) works in the sense that as soon as the page is rendered, the element is detected and the alert is triggered. But this is not what I need.

The latest function I've tried is:

```
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
return (
    (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
    rect.bottom >= 0 &&
    rect.right >= 0 &&
    rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
);
};

    if (isVisible(document.getElementById("cover"))) {
    alert('Cover VISIBLE');
}

else alert('Cover NOT VISIBLE');
```

Where the alerts are for debugging purposes.

I can get the on click event to work for #cover but I can't get 'is visible' to work.  Help would be much appreciated.

PS How do I do a newline when posting a comment to  a post? I keep posting the comment before finishing the comment. :|

Comment: You cannot have line breaks in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
var thisElement = document.getElementById("cover");
if ($(thisElement).isVisible() {
  alert('Cover VISIBLE');
}
else {
  alert('Cover NOT VISIBLE');
}
```

... since you created the `isVisible` function as a jQuery function, it should operate on a jQuery element.

Comment: That didn't work either ie neither alert was triggered. It's as if the function is not triggered itself. The call to the script is in the Head section of the HTML: <script src="js/checkVisible.js"></script>

Comment: Can you console log `thisElement` to see if it was correctly captured?

Comment: Then try executing `$(thisElement).isVisible()` if it has been captured correctly ... this should give an indicator of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys...I achieved what I wanted by going back to the isInViewport function which I had previously tried unsuccessfully, and making it work.